# Composition of two differentiable map is an invertible map then:

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

This question was asked in my Analysis quiz and I am not able to prove it. So, I am psting here in search of help.

> Let $m \neq n$ and suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be two differentiable maps such that $g(f(x))$ is $\mathbb{R}^n \to  \mathbb{R}^n$ be an invertible map. Then show that n<m and rank $(D(f(a))  \leq n $ and rank $(D(f(a))\leq m$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Attempt: Invertibilityof g(f(x)) implies surjectivity of f(g(x)) by which I deduced that n<m. But, unfortunately I am not able to understand which result I should use in proving  argument related to rank(D(f(a)). Can you please help with that?

I have been following my lecture notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are being confused by the calculus: what remains is just a linear algebra problem. In particular, $(D f)(a)$ is a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, i.e. an $m \times n$ matrix. Hence $\operatorname{rank} (D f)(a) \leq \min\{\dim \mathbb{R}^n, \dim\mathbb{R}^m\}$, i.e. $\operatorname{rank} (D f)(a) \leq m, n$.